# Sulfuric Acid Resistance / Conductivity

Tags: electrochemistry, conductivity

I diluted sulfuric acid in deionized water in order to get a 10% $\ce{H2SO4}$ solution.

I was going to use this solution as a cathode of a porous sample to measure its electrical properties.

However, this solution has a quite high resistivity (~200 ohm.cm DC).

I checked several sources that tell me that I should be measuring a lower resistance.

Does anyone has an idea of what may be happening?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Could you provide more information about the "several sources" you mention? Links would great if possible. I have also edited your question to make the chemical formula of sulfuric acid look like $\ce{H2SO4}$. You can learn how to do this for yourself from the [faq].

Comment: Give all details of your set-up including electrode and the ohmmeter.  Did you check for an breaks in the wiring?